# Bitnami djangostack Not serving any pages degault/app

Tags: apache, apache2, google-compute-engine, httpd.conf, bitnami

I am new to cloud jargon. I initiated a GCE instance sometime back and installed bitnami djangostack. It all worked fine.
One fine day due to some issue instance restarted **and changed my server IP**.On typing new IP in browser Apache2 Debian page was back.This previously showed Bitnami default page.
I restarted each service using `/opt/bitnami/ctl` script but apache was not running.
Searched and changed default port to 8080 and from 443 to 8443 in httpd.conf file.
Apache started. But still when I type on browser new server IP - I get connection refused error.Also cannot load any apps using http://serverip/Project/ which previously used to work.

**Apache Error log** says

```
localhost:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matched server name.
```

Searched and **changed below in /apache2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf**

```
ServerName to localhost from www.example.com
```

But nothing is working and I still get same error.

Can anyone help.

Comment: Hi Bitnami developer here. It seems that the System's Apache's service was started before starting the Bitnami services so you got the errors when trying to start the Bitnami's Apache. Could you please revert the changes in the httpd.conf configuration file, stop the system's service `sudo service httpd stop` and start the Bitnami services again?

Comment: Hi Jota - I did the above and restarted all via `/opt/bitnami/ctlscript start`.

Comment: Just went thru Apache error log. See this  `localhost:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name`